# GitHub Actions is stuck on loading

Tags: node.js, github, github-actions, cicd

I'm creating CI in GitHub Actions ([link to repo](https://github.com/danielchochlinski/Backend-Bug-Tracker)).

This is my current YAML file:

```yaml
# This workflow will do a clean installation of node dependencies, cache/restore them, build the source code and run tests across different versions of node
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-nodejs

name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: ["dev"]

jobs:
  DEV:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: DEV

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    env:
      PORT: 8000
      MONGO_DB_URL_DEV: ${{ secrets.MONGO_DB_URL_DEV }}

    steps:
      - name: Check env
        run: echo $MONGO_DB_URL_DEV

      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: "npm"

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Build
        run: npm run build

      - name: Start app
        run: npm run start
```

Dependencies are installed correctly, the build process is succesful as well, then it proceeds to starting the app.

The output in GitHub is:

```
Run npm run start
  
> bug-tracker@1.0.0 start
> ts-node src/server.ts
app is listening on 8000
mongo db connected: cluster0-shard-00-00.f3to2.mongodb.net
```

This is the correct output, I expect. I have Port listening on 8000 and mongo cluster connected; however, the yellow circle is spinning and doesn't stop.

The longest I have allowed it to go on for was over an hour.

Has anybody faced such a problem? Or is able to point me to the right direction?

Comment: Of course it will keep spinning. When you start the app this way, it blocks and prevents the workflow from continuing. Why Are you starting the app in the workflow?

Comment: Still new to pipelines, trying to create checks, build, test and start, if everything is okay then merge with the branch

Comment: Usually, the step to see if it starts isn't done in the build pipeline or on the agent. And even if you wanted to do it here, you'll need to start the site in the background and then wait for it to load. Then clean up by killing it.

Comment: so it should end on running tests?

Comment: You might. Or you're going to have to script starting the app in the background, verifying it works correctly and killing it.