# How i run dotnet on self-hosted for deploy

Tags: .net, nginx, .net-core, github-actions, cicd

I run github action for ci/cd but my dotnet c# project is can't run

set-up

- I hosted my github action on aws EC2 ubuntu
- deploy by nginx waitng for localhost port 5000 running ( my c# project)
- My nginx config
  [image]
- My github action
  [image]
  [image]
- it still running....

I want to run dotnet on port 5000 by using github action but i want to finish the action after run all script

Comment: Very similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75986002/github-actions-is-stuck-on-loading#comment134046471_75986002

Comment: This might be a XY-problem here. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pipeline never ends because you are running the app inside the job/pipeline. For as long as the app stays online, the job will keep waiting for the process to finish.

You should, for example, make a **service** that runs dotnet and the .dll file. Then, in your job, you should simply **start the service**. The job will continue after it starts the service, and the app will be running in the background.